# Rails / ActiveRecord - How can I store the result of a order by calculation on the model to be used later in the request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, dds-format

So I have a spatial query that get's locations based on a given lat/lng. The query looks like this:

```
Location.
  where("ST_Distance(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (#{lng} #{lat})', #{SRID})) < ?", max_distance)
  .order("ST_Distance(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (#{lng} #{lat})', #{SRID}))")
```

Since the lat/lng here are the user's lat/lng, and the DB is performing a distance query on each record. How can I save this result for later use? In my view I display the distance, and I end up having to recalculate this later on, in a much slower way.

What is the best way to store the result of this order equation?

Comment: How long do you need to hold onto the result of the calculation? What happens between when it's calculated and when you want to use it again?

Comment: @oneWorkingHeadphone I would like to use it in the view. So I would get the lat/lng from the user, use them to get locations from the DB, then display those locations, and also show the distance from the user to the location. My underststanding is that in SQL you can perform a calculation and store it in a variable name. Would it be possible to do that with this calculation, then use it to sort, and also perhaps assign that calculation to a virtual attribute on Location?

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution that does what I want it to using `select AS`

```
Location.
  .select("*, ST_Distance(location, ST_GeomFromText(#{point}, #{SRID})) AS distance_from_user")
  .where("ST_Distance(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (#{lng} #{lat})', #{SRID})) < ?", max_distance)
  .order("distance_from_user")
```

This enables me to call `location.distance_from_user` in the view and get the value that was calculated in the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I mis-understood your question so re-writing below:

Store your lookup as a method on the model (I'll assume all the values are stored in the user table, but I haven't worked with SRIDs so if those are not saved, feel free to modify):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def location_lookup(lng=self.lng, lat=self.lat, SRID=self.SRID)
    result = Location
    .where("ST_Distance(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (#{lng} #{lat})', #{SRID})) < ?", max_distance)
    .order("ST_Distance(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (#{lng} #{lat})', #{SRID}))")
  end
end
```

Then assuming that you are using Devise, or otherwise define the user with a lookup, you can call this in whatever controller action by calling `current_user.location_lookup` or pass arguments if required. Between caching and storing this as an instance variable, I wouldn't think it would be hitting the DB that often for a single user.

Comment: Why can't I do something in the DB? For example, if I do `user = User.select("*, users.id AS another_id").last`, I now have the user id as `user.id` OR `user.another_id`. ActiveRecord automatically creates an attr for that select. I want to somehow use this to perform the calculation, order on it, then select it so it's assigned to each record that gets passed to the view.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. See edit, does that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store this data in the database, you'll need a new table, as storing on either the User or Location table won't work since there's a many-to-many relationship between Users and their possible locations.

You could create a new `Distances` table that has a `user_id`, `location_id`, and `distance`, and set this up with an association in rails:

```
class User
  has_many :distances
end
```

and then query the distance from a user:

```
current_user.distances.where("distance < 5").order("distance")
```

In your case though, storing in the database isn't necessary, since you only need the data available for the remainder of the request. You can do this by selecting out another (computed) column along with your model, which will "persist" into your view:

```
Location
  .select("*")
  .select("ST_Distance(location, ST_GeomFromText('POINT (#{lng} #{lat})', #{SRID}) AS distance_from_user")
  .where("distance_from_user < ?", max_distance)
  .order("distance_from_user")
```

And then in your view, use `distance_from_user` as you would any other attribute:

Comment: I don't want to store this in the DB, as that wouldn't make any sense, the chance of a user ever sending the exact same lat/lng is close to zero. Instead it should be dynamically calculated for each request. The point is, the DB is already doing the calculation, and does it much faster than Ruby would. So rather than doing the calculation in the DB for the `order`, only the throw it away and recalculate the same thing in Ruby later, I'm looking for a solution to save the DB calculation and use that.

Comment: @PeterR Look at the second part of my solution then, that includes it in the calculation and also selects it so it's "part" of the model (it works the same as any other attribute). You can reuse `distance_from_user` in your view without a recalculation occurring.